# How do I modify Kadane's algorithm to find out the subarray elements that contribute to the maximum sum?

Tags: c++, algorithm, c++11, kadanes-algorithm

**What I've done so far:**

I've found out the sum using Kadane's algorithm.

I created a vector "res" that stores the elements when conditions are satisfied.

**Problem:**
For example, when the input is an array: {-2, -3, 4, -1, -2, 1, 5, -3}
The result array contains the right subarray elements along with 1 extra element which is added when the condition fails.

**tldr:** The code returns the output subarray as : {4 -1 -2 1 5 -3}
whereas, the correct output should be {4, -1, -2, 1, 5}

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int i, a[10], n, temp_sum=0, final_sum=0;
    vector<int> res;
    cin >> n;                               //getting array size input
    for(i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        cin >> a[i];                        //getting array elements input
    }
    temp_sum=a[0];                          //initializing to first element
    final_sum=a[0];
    for(i=1; i<n; i++)
    {
        if(a[i]>temp_sum+a[i])       //if element is greater than sum so far
        {
            temp_sum = a[i];
            res.clear();
            res.push_back(a[i]);
        }
        else
        {
            temp_sum = a[i] + temp_sum;
            cout << temp_sum << " " << final_sum << " " << a[i] << "\n";
            res.push_back(a[i]);
        }
        if(temp_sum>final_sum)
        {
            final_sum = temp_sum;
        }
    }
    cout << final_sum << "\n";                  //displaying maximum sum
    for(i=0; i<res.size(); i++)                 //displaying result vector
    {
        cout << res[i] << " ";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Is there a reason for the `c`-tag or do you just find it aesthetically pleasing?

Comment: Seem problem is unclear. Try to formulate it better and give an example.

Comment: formulated better by adding an example i/o case. @MBo

Answer (score 0):

Note that you execute

```
res.push_back(a[i]);
```

in any case and don't refresh res if `if(temp_sum>final_sum)` failed

By the way, condition `if(a[i]>temp_sum+a[i])` is equal to  `temp_sum <0`  (does not influence the result)